# How to have more than one foreign key?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble adding more than 1 foreign key to my tables, I am getting the error:

```
"Error report -
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view"
```

I tried making the table without the third foreign key and it worked so I think its something to do with the last key but not really sure. (I put spaces in between the SQL to make it easier to read.)

```
CREATE TABLE ORDER(
ORDERID CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
HOUSETYPE CHAR(2),
CHAIR CHAR(2),
PERSON CHAR(2),
PAYDAY DATE,
MENUPRICE NUMBER(4,2),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCESESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY(ORDERID),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCESESSION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(HOUSETYPE) REFERENCES 
    HOUSE(HOUSETYPE),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCESESSION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(PAYDAY) REFERENCES PERSON(PAYDAY),
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCESESSION_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(MENUPRICE) REFERENCES 
    MENU(MENUPRICE)
);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) Right now, your post is an unreadable mess and it's unlikely to be answered in it's current form.

Comment: Does each FK reference a PK or UNIQUE constraint in the referenced table?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key must reference another table primary key, my guess is that some of you foreign keys don't reference the primary key of the other table.

> A FOREIGN KEY is a key used to link two tables together.
>
> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that
>   refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.
>
> The table containing the foreign key is called the child table, and
>   the table containing the candidate key is called the referenced or
>   parent table.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key must reference another table primary key so make sure you are doing that with the right name of the primary key. For example:

```
CONSTRAINT CONFERENCESESSION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(PAYDAY) REFERENCES PERSON(PAYDAY)
```

Make sure that in table `PERSON` you have `PRIMARY KEY` with name `PAYDAY`.